# Having difficulty in moving Nav bar to the left using bootstrap4

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi everyone i have a code for nav-bar and i want to move it to the left side of 
 the form, its staying on the right side of the form,

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle " type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu " aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

i have tried using floating to the left and using align-left it's still staying on the right side of the form what alternative can solve this issue?/ Thank you.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap 3 or 4? You have tagged 3 though. Just checking

Answer (score 0):

Kindly update your whole HTML page with navbar code. As running the code you have given is showing on left side of the browser.
 Take a look:

[image]